# Characterization of trace space of univalent functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose we have some univalent function $f \colon D \to f(D) = \Omega$, where we assume for simplicity that $D$ is the unit disk and $\partial \Omega$ is smooth. It is well known that $f \colon \partial D \to \partial \Omega$ is also smooth. What can we say about the set of this trace $f |_{\partial D}$? That is, if we have a sufficiently smooth $g \colon \partial D \to \partial \Omega$, then when can we assert that $g$ is the trace of a univalent function, say $h \colon D \to h(D) = \Omega$, such that $h |_{\partial \Omega} = g$? Also, can we say something similar in case $D$ is a multiply connected, possibly unbounded region?

Comment: the answer is no - a necessary condition is for $g$ to be in some Hardy space - in the bounded case one needs $g \in H^{\infty}$; for example, it is trivial that $z \to \bar z=1/z$ is a very smooth automorphism of the circle but it is not a boundary function

Comment: this being said, it is true (a theorem of Kirillov) that any (smooth) diffeomorphism of the unit circle comes from Riemann maps (though one needs to take both the inner and outer domain of a smooth Jordan curve and compose the two corresponding boundary maps) - see this article by Ebenfelt, Khavinson and Shapiro for details, references etc https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4567

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for the reference. Yes I know that there are smooth functions on the boundary which do not necessarily extend to a univalent map. I wanted to know when such smooth functions can be indeed extended, i.e. whether the trace space of univalent maps on, say the unit disk, can be completely characterized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An injective continuous map $g$ on the unit circle is the trace of a univalent function $f$ iff $g \in H^{\infty}$

If $g$  is a trace then $g \in H^{\infty}$ trivially

(eg $\int_0^{2\pi}g(e^{it})e^{int}dt=\lim_{r \to 1, r<1}\int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{it})e^{int}dt=0, n \ge 1$)

If $g \in H^{\infty}, f(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}P(r,\theta -t)g(e^{it})dt$ is analytic in the open disc with boundary limit $g$, where $P(r,\theta -t)=\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos (\theta-t)+r^2}$ is the Poisson Kernel

(here the assumption $g \in H^{\infty}$ is crucial as this implies $f=P(g)$ is analytic not only harmonic)

But then $f$ is $1-1$ by the argument principle since $g$ is so

(here one needs to be careful since $g$ may not be smooth and $g(\partial \mathbb D)=\partial \Omega$ may not be a rectifiable Jordan curve, but one can use RMT to map $\Omega$ back to $\mathbb D$ with $h$ which extends to a boundary homeomorphism so $h\circ f$ is an analytic map from the unit disc to itself that is a homeomorphism on the boundary, hence it can be extended analytically beyond the boundary by the reflection principle, the argument principle now can be applied and $h\circ f$ is univalent, hence $f$ is since we know $h$ is a Riemann map)

Edit later - added a bit more detail about the argument principle as requested:

the argument principle says that if $f$ is analytic on the closed unit disc and $f(\partial \mathbb D)=J$ is a piecewise smooth Jordan curve (one has conformality only up to some finite many points at the boundary even if $f$ extends beyond the disc, though of course $f'(z)=0$ can have only finitely many solutions on the boundary - as the example $f(z)=z^2-2z$ shows that actually can happen since $f$ is $1-1$ in the closed unit disc but $f'(1)=0$ so the image of the unit circle under $z^2-2z$ has a "corner" at $-1$) then the equation $f(z)=w$ has precisely the index of $w$ wr $J$ roots for $w$ not in $J$ (this number being $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-w}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_J \frac{1}{\zeta-w}d\zeta$ since $\zeta=f(z), d\zeta = f'(z)dz$ is then a (piecewise) smooth change of variables) and that is $1$ if $w$ is inside and $0$ if $w$ outside

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Could you please explain how the argument principle implies injectivity? Also, do you think an analogous result would hold if the domain is $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{D}$?

Comment: added the argument principle detail - for functions in $\mathbb C - \mathbb D$ one usually can reduce the problem to functions on the disc though it depends on the behaviour at infinity (if one has a simple pole or not there - univalence on the exterior of the disc implies infinity is either removable singularity or simple pole); in the removable case one just takes $h(z)=f(1/z)$ which is then analytic and univalent on the unit disc, while in the pole case, one picks some $c$ outside of the range of $f$ and one takes $h(z)=1/(f(1/z)-c)$ etc

Comment: (comment continuation) - in both cases, one still needs some hypothesis at the boundary, so $f(\partial \mathbb D)=J$ Jordan and then one can pick $c$ as above in the interior of $J$; this will give appropriate conditions on $g$ the boundary function from the unit disc case - so for example if $J$ circles zero, one can take $c=0, h(z)=1/f(1/z)$ which is the usual normalization in the theory